# How long does it take for a Prime Evil to be revived?

Tags: diablo-iii

According to lore if you kill a Prime Evil it will return in time. That's why people always try to imprison them first. But what time exactly have to pass before Diablo (or any other Prime Evil) revives after being killed?

Comment: Are you asking about game mechanics? (As evidenced by the use of the term 'respawn'). Or are you asking about lore?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz he does state "According to *lore*"

Comment: @Ben And yet, he uses mechanical terms like 'Respawn'. Which is why it's *not clear* what he's asking about.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I understand that. Hence my edit to (hopefully) clear up the confusion.

Comment: But you clearly disagreed with that, so... never mind. Lol

Comment: @Ben I don't think that it's particularly helpful, when provided with a question with two very reasonable interpretations, and no evidence as to which is intended, to simply assume one is intended, edit it,and reopen the question. This is *why we close questions as unclear* in the first place. The OP is welcome to return, edit and/or clarify his intention, and then we can reopen the question. There's no reason to jump the gun on that on his behalf, IMO.

Comment: Updated my question. I don't know what other word I should use to describe that creature died and come back to life.

Comment: I believe I found a good substitution for you instead of the word respawn.

Comment: @Poma could you possibly provide us with a reference as to where it is stated "in the lore" of the Prime Evils returning?

Comment: Revive and respawn are both not the correct words to use. Instead you should say "Return to their original power" or something along those lines.

Comment: I think my use of the word reborn is more accurate before it got changed, but I don't want to get into an editing war :P

Answer (score 1):

***DIABLO LORE SPOILERS AHEAD***

"The Prime Evils will return in time."

This is a vague statement and misleading. This is because you think that they were "killed". They were in fact NOT "killed". They were defeated in the battles in heaven (because they invaded it). They were banished to the Mortal Realm (Earth).

Here, they gained their strength back and feasted on the weakness of men. Diablo, for instance, gained control over Aiden, your hero of Diablo 1 and used him to free his brothers and gain power.

No one really knows if they have truly defeated the Great Evils (the combination of the 3 Prime Evils and the 4 Lesser Evils).